# Send email to people with access to sheet when changes are made in specific dropdown areas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, email

My apologies in advance for my ignorance -- I am totally new to all of this!

I have set up a project tracking sheet that myself and one other coworker uses, and we have a column where we use drop downs to track whether each project is either 'Testing' 'In Progress' 'Requested' 'Update Requested' 'Published'. We want Google to send out an email notification to the two of us when any of those drop downs are changed to any new status.

[image: image of drop down list in spreadsheet]

I know that Sheets has the option to send out an email notice when anything in the sheet changes, but that would end up with us just getting spammed out with emails. We only need to know when any of the drop downs change.

Any help with this would be so, so appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the drop down located?  Please share an image of your spreadsheet.  You might want to remove private info.  The only changes we can trigger on are user edits.

Comment: @BridgetChase You should be aware that sharing your spreadsheet will unavoidably expose your email address.

Answer (score 1):

This will capture the changes.  All you need to do is create an installable trigger and setup the GmailApp.sendEmail line. You can disable the modeless dialog.  I just used it for the animation.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet10') {return;}
  if(e.range.rowStart==1 && e.range.columnStart>8 && e.range.columnStart<11) {
    var html=Utilities.formatString('<br />Cell: %s Old Value: %s New Value: %s',e.range.getA1Notation(),e.oldValue?e.oldValue:'null',e.value?e.value:'null');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),"Changes");
    //GmailApp.sendEmail('oneemail,twoemail', 'Changes','' ,{htmlBody:html});
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: `createOnEditTriggerForSpreadsheet` is that a new model? I haven't seen it in the documentation. With the greatest respect for you and your work, this question has so many precedents on StackOverFlow that It deserved to be closed rather than answered. In any event, it might be helpful to explain why the questioner can't just use a simple trigger, and why an installable trigger is required.